# Fixed Gabor Filter Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network, pytorch, gabor-filter

I'm trying to build a CNN with some conv layers where half of the filters in the layer are fixed and the other half is learnable while training the model. But I didn't find anything about that.

what I'm trying to do is similar to what they did in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04748.pdf

Is there a way to do that in Keras, Pytorch...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. In PyTorch you can use [`nn.Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d) and

1. set its `weight` parameter manually to your desired filters
2. exclude these weights from learning

A simple example would be:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.conv_learning = nn.Conv2d(1, 5, 3, bias=False)
        self.conv_gabor = nn.Conv2d(1, 5, 3, bias=False)
        # weights HAVE TO be wrapped in `nn.Parameter` even if they are not learning
        self.conv_gabor.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 5, 3, 3))

    def forward(self, x):
        y = self.conv_learning(x)
        y = torch.sigmoid(y)
        y = self.conv_gabor(y)

        return y.mean()

model = Model()
xs = torch.randn(10, 1, 30, 30)
ys = torch.randn(10)
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

# we can exclude parameters from being learned here, by filtering them
# out based on some criterion. For instance if all your fixed filters have
# "gabor" in name, the following will do
learning_parameters = (param for name, param in model.named_parameters()
                             if 'gabor' not in name)
optim = torch.optim.SGD(learning_parameters, lr=0.1)

epochs = 10
for e in range(epochs):
    y = model(xs)
    loss = loss_fn(y, ys)

    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat related question I asked on [Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342365/why-not-set-a-static-first-layer-in-cnn) that you can reference and find additional information.

To avoid having to build your own custom layers that allow for partial freezing, maybe it would be best to create two layers where one is frozen and one is not. Then the next layer could connect to both of them and the rest of the network would be the same. You could then use a little transfer learning and transfer the first layer from a pre-trained network into the frozen layer. For this you could use [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

Here is a simple example of how you could make this work.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications import InceptionV3

# Sample CNN
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
frozen_layer = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), use_bias=False, trainable=False, name="frozen_layer")(input_layer)
thawed_layer = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), trainable=True)(input_layer)
concat = layers.concatenate([frozen_layer, thawed_layer])
another_layer = layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), trainable=True)(concat)
output_layer = layers.Dense(10)(another_layer)
model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[output_layer])

# Build a pre-trained model to extract weights from
transfer_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

assert transfer_model.layers[1].get_weights()[0].shape == model.get_layer(name="frozen_layer").get_weights()[0].shape

# Transfer the weights 
model.get_layer(name="frozen_layer").set_weights(transfer_model.layers[1].get_weights())
```